# Align text inside a fixed width button

Tags: html, css, alignment

I tried to align a ">" text to a button with fixed width. I tried with align text but it is not center aligned from observation.

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <style>
    .naviButton {
      height:34px;
      width:16px;
      color:grey;
      text-align:center;
      position:relative;
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>

    <button class="naviButton"><</button>

    </body>
    </html>
```

If I delete the fixed width, the ">" will be centered middle.

I kind of suspect that the aligned element here is actually the start position of ">" text. However, can i centered the mid of text?

Anyone have any idea that can it be centered middle with fixed width. Thank you so much!

Comment: Add padding: 0;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `padding: 0;`

```css
.naviButton {
   height:34px;
   width:16px;
   color:grey;
   text-align:center;
   position:relative;
   padding: 0;
 }
```

```html
<button class="naviButton"><</button>
```